# EF Code First - run Update-Database from Azure portal

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database

I am currently looking at the best way to update our database on Azure. Running Visual Studio to just run "**Update-Database**" command seems a bit cumbersome. Is there a way to deploy to Azure and then from Azure portal run the "**Update-Database**" command? Or is this just a standard way even when updating production database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about running the powershell commands from azure portal directly.

However you could use System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion to do this for you automatically for deployments to azure. This can be automatically added to your web.config, if you select update-database in the publish profile wizard. Details on how to do this can be found here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 2):

As already answered, you may setup your application to automatically apply new migrations to the database on startup.

Another way is to setup release process using Visual Studio Team Services and then setup database migration using powershell. Some details available here: [VSTS Build Task that runs script on multiple shards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49844120/vsts-build-task-that-runs-script-on-multiple-shards/49861623#49861623)